# Menu Doesnt Hover the selected menu tab

Tags: css, html, menu, hover

I am struggling in this. I have menu out there, and the problem here is when I choose Eat & Drink menu, or any other menu tab from there, I want that menu tab to be active—in other words, highlighted. I tried a lot but couldn't succeed.

Can anyone explain me whats wrong?

Check it here:

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/96VMj/`
```

Comment: do you mean that you want to stay selected once clicked?

Comment: With a problem like this, it's always helpful to cut your code down to the absolute minimum necessary to illustrate the problem.  Supplying a link to jsfiddle so people can see what happens easily will also make people more likely to try and help.

Comment: @Richard Sorry i am kinda new .

Comment: @SanderH What i meant is when i select rooms.html tab i want that tab to be highlighted, 
When i use #rooms it is working but when i use rooms.html its not working.

Comment: @Richard Surely i have corrected that now...

Comment: The Jsfiddle is working

Comment: @Gimmy Yes JS fiddle is working, but does the fiddle which i posted work as i said above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a css class to the selected item, then add styling to that class in your css.  
For instance, if you have a page `Rooms` that is defined in `rooms.html`:

1. Add `class = 'active-menu-item'` to the rooms menu item. in `rooms.html`.
2. Add styling for `.active-menu-item` to your css file.

Repeat this process for each page.